# How to include absolute URL for Bundling in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bundle

Whenever I include absolute URL in BundleConfig.cs, I end with the error only Application relative URL's are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to , add the ~ to the start of your path, . The ~ is synonymous to the application root.